# how to invoke module in ocaml

Tags: ocaml, ocamlbuild

I have wrote a ocaml file which includes Vector module and Matrix module, and I want to invoke Vector module in the Matrix module, but the compiler said that Vector module is unbound module. I don't know why,here is my code

```
module Vector = 
Struct
   body
end

module Matrix = 
Struct
    body
end
```

they are in the same .ml file, how can I write code in Matrix module to invoke Vector module(exclude using functor)

Comment: `Struct` should have a lowercase "s": `struct` is the right keyword. Could you show us your actual code or at least a minimal example reproducing your problem?

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing wrong with the code you show, so it's not really possible to answer. Here is a tiny example that works (`m.ml`):

```
module Vector =
struct
    let f x = x + 7
end

module Matrix =
struct
    let g x = 2 * Vector.f x
end
```

The compiler has no trouble with it:

```
$ ocamlc -c m.ml
$
```

One thing to be aware of is that every OCaml file introduces a module named after the file. So the modules in the above example are named `M.Vector` and `M.Matrix`, because the file is named `m.ml`.

If this doesn't help, you'll need to show more code. Ideally, you should show the smallest amount of code that reproduces the problem.